# Update LikedBy column through Rest Api

Tags: rest, lookup-column, update, share

I am trying to update the LikedBy column in Discussion Board. LikedBy, it seems, is a lookup column. Can you let me know the what the payload would be? I will need to update the Likedby Id and Likedby Title. I am able to update the likescount, but not the Likedby Id and LikedBy Title.

I am sort of stuck on this.

Comment: What does the lookup field point to?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to `Ratings` fields, then here are use cases that shows on how to set proper payload:

1) clear all likes

```
var itemProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.DiscussionsListItem" },
    "LikedByStringId": { "results" :  [] },
    "LikesCount" : 0
};
```

2)set like by user with `id = 1`

```
var itemProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.DiscussionsListItem" },
    "LikedByStringId": { "results" :  ["1"] },
    "LikesCount" : 1
};
```

> Note: `LikesCount` property should be provided in conjunction with
>   `LikedByStringId`

**Example**

```
var listTitle = "Discussions";
var itemProperties = {
    '__metadata': { "type": "SP.Data.DiscussionsListItem" },
    "LikedByStringId": { "results" :  ["1"] },
    LikesCount : 1
};
var itemId = 1;
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;


updateListItem(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,itemProperties)
.done(function(item)
{
    console.log('List item has been updated');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

where

```
function executeJson(options) 
{
    var headers = options.headers || {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(options.method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: options.url,   
       type: options.method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(options.method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(options.payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}


function updateListItem(webUrl,listTitle,itemId,itemPayload)
{
     var options ={
        url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + itemId + ")",  
        method: "POST",
        headers : {
          "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
          "If-Match": "*"
        },
        payload: itemPayload    
     };     
     return executeJson(options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
I was able to update the Likedby.. with this..
But I don't want to clear the existing likes..
I want my userid to(for example ) to be added to the already existing userid collection.

I was trying this.. by first getting the existing userid's and then adding the new userid..  but I  have issues with this approach.
Is there any other way.. by which I can append the new userid to existing user Id's collection.

Comment: @Sony, follow [setLike.js](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/cdaaf82007b7bbb266da377b5d2a2f29), it demonstrates a generic way (it simulates  Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation.setLike method to some extent) to like/unlike a resource

Comment: @Sony, if you find this answer helpful, you could also consider to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)